# "Склеить" данные в AJAX data

Tags: jquery, ajax

Всем доброго времени суток!
Появился следующий вопрос:
Есть ajax-запрос:

```
$("#first_form").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "rest.php",
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Спасибо за заявку!");
    });
    return false;
});
```

Как сделать, чтобы в параметре data передать еще несколько параметров?
Мне нужно, чтобы туда передавались, к примеру, переменные first и second, а в php файл данные в итоге поступали в массиве $_POST, т.е. $_POST['first'] и $_POST['second']?

Заранее спасибо!)

Comment: а на стороне сервера php?

Comment: Не понял вопроса, если честно
на стороне сервера из параметра data вынимаются данные из отправленной формы #first_form, т.е. $_POST['name'] и $_POST['phone']
Мне к этому нужно добавить еще данные, которые не входят в форму #first_form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this).serialize()` возвращает вам `form-urlencoded` строку вида:

```
param1=val&param2=val2
```

На сервере, это благополучно парсится в массив `$_POST`.

В `jQuery` есть функция [$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/), которая превращает js-объект в такую строку.

Ничто не мешает вам через '&' добавить нужные вам данные:

```
$("#first_form").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "rest.php",
        data: [$(this).serialize(), $.param({second: 222})].join('&')
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Спасибо за заявку!");
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Использовать для этого JSON формат:

```
$("#first_form").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "rest.php",
        data: { first: $(this).serialize(), second: 'blah' }
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Спасибо за заявку!");
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Вот дамп вашего кода:
array(2) {
  ["first"]=>
  string(20) "first=123&second=123"
  ["second"]=>
  string(4) "blah"
}

а мне нужно, чтобы данные, которые есть в массиве $(this).serialize() шли в массив $_POST с такими же индексами

Comment: т.е. просто data: $(this).serialize() 
возвращает массив с данными, полученными из формы #first_form

А мне нужно в этот массив записать еще несколько параметров

Comment: @Alexxosipov, приконкатенируйте через `+'&'+$.params({second: 'asd'})`

Answer (score 1):

Не профи в jquery, но я обычно для POST-запроса использую

```
$.post('test.php', {first:'Ivan',second:'Petrov'}).done(function(result) {
    alert(result);
});
```

Comment: Уже думал насчет этого, но заказчику нужен именно ajax :(

Comment: Вспомнил, пишешь так: data: { name: "Ivan", second_name: "Petrov" }

Comment: @Alexxosipov post - это просто синтаксический сахар. под капотом - ajax.

Comment: Я понимаю, но ответил выше по этому поводу:
Есть форма #first_form, она возвращает массив, который я получаю в результате `$(this)serialize()`
Который я записываю в параметр ajax data
Мне нужно в data записать еще 2 параметра, т.е. на ломаном и не работающем синтаксисе это будет выглядеть примерно так:
`data: ($(this).serialize() + {field : field })`